# Building a workstation computer for Image processing?

Tags: memory, motherboard, computer-building

I am taking a gigapixel image my goal is 50gigapixel and shooting is almost done , i am doing some research to build a workstation so i can stitch images together , my questions is !

Could u suggest some dual cpu mainboard that works fine with xeon 5500+ , with 64GB+ ram support ?

My other question is which hardware is most important in image processing , all i see in story of gigapixel panoramas is they have dual xeon and 32gb+ ram ? i wonder if i am doing this right , i mean they don't post information on graphic card , mainboard and stuff !

I did asked several websites , but nothing best answer was get some high-end workstation and plenty of hours , i don't want to purchase ready to use workstations, i wanna build it up

Thanks in advance

Comment: -1 because of crappy formating, flagged because of shopping rec. Please read the faq again, shopping recs are off topic on superuser. (and most other SE sites)

Comment: DID U READ IT , IT'S TWO QUESTION , which hardware is most important in image processing ? , at least you could answer one , or just let others do it

Comment: You want a speedy CPU and lots and lots of RAM, that's all. A fast hard drive is also important, maybe use an SSD as the working drive. Graphics card, and a specific mainboard, not *that* important. As for your question: Consider capitalizing the personal pronoun "i" – it makes your post look really unprofessional and lazy if you don't do it.

Comment: @slhck my native language is french , sorry for my poor English

Comment: looks like we've got some down-voting addicts around here

Comment: @echolab no reason for screaming :) you should actually read the faq, there should be a sentence about only asking one question per question.

Comment: @Celeritas What exactly do you mean? *This question does not show research effort, it's unclear* sums it up pretty much for me. Why would you *not* downvote the question, if I may ask? This has nothing to do with addiction – and by the way, did you know you're allowed to cast 40 downvotes a day?

Comment: @Walter Maier-Murdnelch They are not two separated ( not-related ) questions , anyway i rest my case, i should ask it at hardware communities !

Comment: @echolab If they are not separated questions how should I be able to answer at least one? (as you told me to)

Comment: Can this question be salvaged through editing? I see a way to phrase both parts lucidly without treading on the "shopping recommendation" button.

Comment: @Walter Maier-Murdnelch what i mean is both related to title of question , this is super users community ,all i think was someone with specialty in hardware gonna guide me through , why i did explained my reason to build workstation !? because maybe someone knows better , maybe someone here have experience in this field , it's crappy, pardon me for my poor English , it's ok , i told ya im gonna ask exact question in some hardware communities, thanks anyway

Comment: See: [How should I choose Hardware? - Super User Blog](http://blog.superuser.com/2011/06/20/qotw-how-should-i-choose-hardware/)

Comment: @slhck I don't see how asking what's good to buy violates community standards?

Comment: @Celeritas The simple fact that we don't do shopping recommendations (*Could u suggest some dual cpu mainboard that works fine with xeon 5500+ , with 64GB+ ram support ?*) — I see some merits in the broader question of what kind of hardware is needed, or where to spend more money, but we've covered that in plenty of other questions if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 2):

I would be less focused on what kind of hardware you need and more focused on taking the quality pictures. I've made 10 Gigapixel images in the past with a Core2Duo, 2GB Ram, 500GB HDD. I've also made terapixel images on a bit beefier of machines, but that was more for proof of concept than it was anything else. The 10 gigapixels was sufficient for a huge poster banner. It took it a bit of time (~5-10 minutes) for a quality patch. An Intel Ivy Bridge Core i7 should do plenty for what you're looking to do.

The Xeon 5500 is expensive and old. You can get much more computing power and better hardware for much less. The Xeon 5550 ranked much further down.

Intel Xeon X5550 @ 2.67GHz  **5,170 Passmark Score**    $1,003.99*

Having a good amount of RAM is always important. You will not need more than 32GB of RAM and can even get away with 8GB-16GB of RAM. If you're looking for an excuse to buy server grade hardware, then by all means go for it, but it's not necessary.

[image]

Comment: Even if you're looking for server-grade hardware, the Xeon E5-1650 (Sandy Bridge) would be a much better choice.  More cores, higher clock speed, faster RAM, more RAM channels, and also has the server features such as ECC.